# Member of sudo group, getting "is not in the sudoers file."

Tags: centos, sudo, group

I am running CentOS 7 web server in a VM on our network, and it all looks like I am in the sudoer list but when I try anything with I get the following error:

```
$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for dragonbite:
dragonbite is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I looked in **/etc/group** and verified I am in the wheel group

```
wheel:x:10:dragonbite
```

I ran **visudo** and verified the *wheel* group is listed

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

So it seems to me that everything is as it should be.  I even tried adding the account from the first user by running

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo dragonbite
```

and got the message, after putting in that account's password

```
usermod: group 'sudo' does not exist
```

strange,... since it uses the *wheel* account as far as I know (CentOS).  So I tried adding a *sudo* group with

```
sudo groupadd sudo
```

and then when I tried to add my account to the sudo group it didn't throw any errors.  But the group *sudo* isn't in the sudoers file, and after adding myself to the *sudo* group I tested it and still get the same message of not being in the sudoers file.

So I am at a loss of what to do next.

- Add sudo to the sudoers list?
- Try making a new account and add it to sudo list?
- Restart the server (do not want to do)?
- Revert to latest VM and re-apply all the patches?

Anybody?

Thanks

Comment: Did you log off and log on again after adding the relevant user to the `wheel` group? What is the output of the `id` command?

Comment: I did log off and on and tried after changing things, and just logged back in after being off maybe 5 minutes and it still doesn't work.  

Running id command from the account I am trying to fix gives me 
`$ id
uid=1001(dragonbite) gid=1001(dragonbite) groups=1001(dragonbite),13(sudo) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`

Comment: Well, for whatever reason you're not in the wheel group.

Comment: It's gotten worse. Now the account that WAS able to run sudo previously, when I typed up the initial piece, is no longer in the sudo/wheel group either!  So now i have no admin rights left.  I think we need to see about reverting the snapshot but does any of this sound like a process or something from a compromised system or attack?

Comment: @dragonbite Did you make changes to the `sudoers` file or do the group membership of the other user? Does the `sudoers` file mention a `sudo` group?

Comment: I didn't make any changes to the sudoers file as far as I remember, and the sudoers file did not make any mention of a sudo group.  At this point we reverted to an older VM snapshot to get control back and both accounts are able to do sudo without any trouble. But now I have to worry about if it were somebody else then it may come up again.

Comment: Does the server or some service need to be restarted to recognize the new users in the wheel group?

Comment: @dragonbite Restarting the server worked for me